# problem after moving from sqllite3 to postgresql database in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, sqlite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftLbl.png)I have changed an existing database for a Django project from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL. As presently i am in development environment, and was carrying some dummy data in my SQlite3 so do not need that data.

After changing the database from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL, I run the makemigrations, and migrate commands, and then created a super user.

Now when i try to access the admin panel, by http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ django is showing me the following error. I have search a lot for the solution, but failed. I would be grateful, if you could please help me in this.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAdzK.png)[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShhpH.png)

Comment: Do not use images for textual data. Copy and paste the text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `sessions` wasn't migrated properly.
Ensure that you have `django.contrib.sessions` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and try migrate the `sessions` again from scratch.

You can do it running:

```
$ python manage.py migrate --fake sessions zero
$ python manage.py migrate sessions
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your reply. I already had the django.contrib.sessions in the installed apps, however, with the migration of fake session zero as advised by you, it worked. Once again thanking you for your support.